# Custom popup box android studio

Tags: android

When the user opens the app for the first time, I want my app to have a custom popup box or a popup model next to a button so which tells what a button does

Here's an example -

[image: id,]

I can use sharedpreferences to make it visible only for the first time.

But, how do I make it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Dialog and customize the position and appearance of it i leave some links below to know how to do it:

diologs on android:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs

changing position of dialog:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-change-the-position-of-the-dialog-on-screen-android

creating custom dialog using Material design:
https://material.io/components/dialogs/

for customizing dialog there is outer ways to but material design is simpler